# Proving a Multivariable Function is differentiable

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Let $$g(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2 + y^4} ,  & \text{if (x,y) $\ne$ (0,0) } \\
0, & \text{if (x,y) = (0,0)}
\end{cases}$$
The objective of the exercise was to study this function, namely to check if the partial derivatives exist, if they are defined in all $\mathbb{R}^2$, continuity, etc. One of the questions was to prove if the derivative of $g(x,y)$, defined as the matrix derivative of the function, is defined at $(0,0)$.

What I did was to calculate the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ via definition. Since both partials exist and are $0$ I concluded that
$
      Df=   \begin{matrix}
        [0 & 0 ]
        \end{matrix}
$

My Professor, on the other hand, claimed this was not enough proof, and used the following definition to prove $Df$ exists:
$$\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} \frac{||f(x)-f(x_0)-T(x-x_0)||}{||x-x_0||}=0$$

My question is: is this definition really necessary to prove $Df$ exists at a point $(0,0)$? And what does this definition mean? What is $T(x-x_0)$ in this definition?

Comment: It's *not* enough to show that $\partial_x f$ and $\partial_y f$ exist at a point to conclude that $f$ is *differentiable* there. It might happen that derivatives along other paths than the axis do not exist.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions

Comment: $T$ is the (purported) matrix derivative.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem is to understand whether or not this function is differentiable at point $(0,0). $ The partial derivatives at this point are zeros - use the definition of partial derivative.
Then differentiability would mean $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^4)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0. $ Using the polar coordinates, we have $0\leq\lim\limits_{\rho\to 0}\frac{\rho\sin^2\varphi}{1+\rho^2\sin^2\varphi\tan^2\varphi }\leq \lim \rho =0. $